# How to search for values in Redis with redis for python

Tags: python, django, http, redis

I'm currently trying to search for entries inside my Redis that match a specific value through an HTTP API the same way you'd do with a regular DB (eg: http://localhost:8000/api?name=John&age=20) with the redis python library (https://pypi.org/project/redis/).

The code I have thus far returns the whole hash, converts each entry into a JSON and adds it to a list

```
import json
import redis
import os

r = redis.StrictRedis(host=os.environ['redis_url'], port=os.environ['redis_port'], password=os.environ['redis_pass'], ssl=True)
result = r.hgetall('Directory')
dic_list = []
for key in result.keys():
    dic_list.append(json.loads(result[key].decode('utf-8')))

return dic_list
```

I know that I can get the value of a specific key with

```
r.hget('Directory', 'key_I_want')
```

However inside each key there is a whole JSON full with information, so for example this would be a key, value example inside of the Directory hash

```
"1": {
     "name": "James", 
      "age": "22", 
      "favorite_color":"Green"
 }, 
"2":{
      "name":"John",
      "age": "20",
      "favorite_color": "red"
  }, 
"3":{
      "name":"Jim",
      "age": "30",
      "favorite_color": "yellow"
  }
```

So I know

```
r.hget('Directory', '1')
```

would return

```
{
     "name": "James", 
      "age": "22", 
      "favorite_color":"Green"
 }
```

But what I really want is to look for every JSON that has specific values, not just to get the values of each key inside the hash, is there any way to actually do that?

Comment: Consider using RediSearch

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you are, maybe, looking for a value within results[key]. Assumin that value is equal to val, try:

```
for key in result.keys():
    if val in result[key].values():
        dic_list.append(json.loads(result[key].decode('utf-8')))
```

for example, if

```
val = "James"
```

Yoy will get all results with James in the value.

You can mix it up a little, change it the way you want it.

Comment: Yes, that's a solution I've used in the past, however I'd like to just send a request to Redis and get the expected values without my intervention.